# Start JMeter thread after another thread

Tags: jmeter

I want to run a thread x times. The thread group contains three samplers and because I dont want them to be mixed up in the result windows I only want to start the next thread when another is finished. I don't want to use a Ramp-Up Period because a thread could take 1 to 20 seconds.

Comment: Why not use loop count = x instead of thread =x ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3 thread groups and module controller (to referencd in the 2 other thread groups the elements in the first one to avoid copy ) and check on test plan the option:

- Run Thread Group sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not very clear, however if you need to limit JMeter to X concurrent threads only the most obvious choice would be going for the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)

[image: Concurrency Thread Group]

As per [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter Part 4 - Stepping Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread) article:

> The Concurrency Thread Group provides a better simulation of user behaviour because it lets you control the length of your test more easily, and it creates replacement threads in case a thread finishes in the middle of the process.

You can install Concurrency Thread Group as a part of **Custom Threads Group** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

---

Regarding your `three listeners` bit, I would recommend reconsidering this approach as per [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) you should not be using any listeners, instead of it you need to [run JMeter in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and use [-l command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to specify the results file name. Once your test is finished you can open the .jtl results file with a listener of your choice or [generate a reporting dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it.

Comment: soory i've meant samplers not listeners

Answer (score 0):

You can use "jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group". The Ultimate Thread Group provides flexible thread scheduling to your test scenario. It allows us to create a scheduled thread with advanced configuration. Start Threads Count, Initial Delay, Startup Time and Hold Load Time can be defined separately for each record.
You can define tasks to run consecutively.

This platform support flexible thread scheduling. You can read detailed wiki docs about the ultimate thread group.

Link: [Loadium.com/wiki/ultimate thread](https://loadium.com/wiki/flexible-thread-scheduling/)